# How to find if any checkbox is NOT checked in an ASP.Net CheckBoxList using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkboxlist

I need to identify if any checkbox in a CheckBoxList is not checked (*repeat **NOT** checked*)  client-side, so that I can change a "select All" option at the top to checked/unchecked using JQuery.

The other operations (to check/uncheck all and unchecking any options unchecking the "Select all" check) all work fine, but it would be nice to also have the "select all" reflect the state of all other checkboxes.

Assuming I already have `var cbs = $('#myCheckBoxList :checkbox')` what would I have to apply to it to find any checkbox where selected == false?

All the examples I have found are all about finding the checked state of a single checkbox, but I need to know if any is not checked.

tried `cbs.find(':[checked="false"]')` etc but I could not find a good example of `find()` filtering by attribute only.

### Full code for the select-all toggle behavior I was writing

**(including final solution derived from Chandu's answer below):**

```
    $(window).load(function () {
        var cbs = $('.myCheckBoxList :checkbox');
        cbs.eq(0).click(function () {
            var toggle = this.checked;
            cbs.attr('checked', toggle);
        });
        cbs.slice(1).click(function () {
            if (!this.checked) {
                cbs.eq(0).attr('checked', false);
            } else {
                cbs.eq(0).attr('checked', cbs.slice(1).filter(':not(:checked)').length == 0);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/  for a bit of documentation

Comment: @2GDev: Yes, buried deep in a comment on that page is an actual answer, but the entire page is about "Matches all elements **that are checked**" I specifically needed the ones not checked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: SO should never have allowed down-voting questions *without penalty*. I am getting sick of retaliatory voting from other users!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `:not` selector along with `:checked`

Try this:

<del>cbs.find(':not(:checked)')</del>

```
cbs.filter(':not(:checked)')
```

or

```
$('#myCheckBoxList :not(:checked)')
```

Comment: The second one is in case you want to get the unchecked boxes right away without referencing #myCheckBoxList

Comment: Am not sure what is the issue you are facing but from the look of it: replace `cbs.eq(0).attr('checked', cbs.find(':not(:checked)'));
` with `cbs.eq(0).attr('checked', cbs.find(':not(:checked)').length > 0);`

Comment: The issue is, when I check all items (except the first one) I want the "Select all" checkbox at the top to be checked. We are so close now, but checking any child checks the "select all", even if others are unchecked. Current code is `cbs.eq(0).attr('checked', cbs.slice(1).find(':not(:checked)').length == 0)`

Comment: @HiTechMagic Can you post the HTML you are using or maybe a jsfiddle post?

Comment: Right sorted it finally: ':checked' is not valid for `find()`, only for `filter()`.

Comment: @HiTechMagic Yep.. If u r interested. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/utkyY/2/

Comment: @Chandu... nice! +1 for the link. You pointed me in the right direction (and you now have 4 upvotes for an incorrect answer... you gotta love the voting system on SO) :)

Comment: @HiTechMagic: I didn't figure it out whn I was trying to write a jsfiddle myself. Will update the answer with the correction.

Comment: I am accepting yours as it was the closest answer to begin with, lead me to the actual answer (and it is now actually correct with your modification).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$('#myCheckBoxList input:not(:checked)')
```

For more info, check [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selectors